# Jquery TableSorter 2.0 widget(multiple columns filtration) plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I want to implement datepicker for a input.The problem is that the inputs are created in tablesorter plugin and i don't know how to do that.

http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-custom.html
Here you can found the plugin's code :
https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js

Comment: I'm working on version 2.4 of my fork of tablesorter, which you linked above. In that version, I'll make the filter widget trigger a "filterInit" event which you can bind to and use to initialize the datepicker. Once I get it done, not sure when yet, I'll post a demo for you.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.7.7, a new option named `filter_formatter` was added to the tablesorter filter widget. You can now add a jQuery UI datepicker range to filter the table content using this option.

You'll need to include a new file named "jquery.tablesorter.widgets-filter-formatter.js" and add the code shown below to add it. This is a [demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html) of it working.

```
$(function() {

  // call the tablesorter plugin
  $("table").tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    // hidden filter input/selects will resize the columns, so try to minimize the change
    widthFixed : true,
    // initialize zebra striping and filter widgets
    widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
    widgetOptions : {
      // jQuery selector string of an element used to reset the filters
      filter_reset : 'button.reset',
      // add custom selector elements to the filter row
      filter_formatter : {

        6 : function($cell, indx){
          return $.tablesorter.filterFormatter.uiDatepicker( $cell, indx, {
            from : '12/1/2012', // default from date
            to   : '2/1/2014',  // default to date
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear : true
          });
        }

      }
    }
  });

});
```